# Angular2: How to subscribe to Http.post observable inside a service and a component properly?

Tags: angular, observable, rxjs5, angular2-http

For a JWT authentification, I make a post request to get the token using the new `Http` module working with Observables now.

I have a simple `Login` component showing the form:

```
@Component({
selector: 'my-login',
    template: `<form (submit)="submitForm($event)">
                <input [(ngModel)]="cred.username" type="text" required autofocus>
                <input [(ngModel)]="cred.password" type="password" required>
                <button type="submit">Connexion</button>
            </form>`
})
export class LoginComponent {
    private cred: CredentialsModel = new CredentialsModel();

    constructor(public auth: Auth) {}

    submitForm(e: MouseEvent) {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.auth.authentificate(this.cred);
    }
}
```

I have a `Auth` service making the request:

```
@Injectable()
export class Auth {
    constructor(public http: Http) {}

    public authentificate(credentials: CredentialsModel) {
        const headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

        this.http.post(config.LOGIN_URL, JSON.stringify(credentials), {headers})
            .map(res => res.json())
            .subscribe(
                data => this._saveJwt(data.id_token),
                err => console.log(err)
            );
    }
}
```

Works well but now I want to display error messages inside my component so I need to subscribe in 2 places (`Auth` for managing success and `Login` for managing error).

I achieved it using `share` operator:

```
public authentificate(credentials: CredentialsModel) : Observable<Response> {
    const headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    const auth$ = this.http.post(config.LOGIN_URL, JSON.stringify(credentials), {headers})
                            .map(res => res.json()).share();

    auth$.subscribe(data => this._saveJwt(data.id_token), () => {});

    return auth$;
}
```

And inside the component:

```
submitForm(e: MouseEvent) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.auth.authentificate(this.cred).subscribe(() => {}, (err) => {
        console.log('ERROR component', err);
    });
}
```

It works but I feel doing it wrong..
I just transpose the way we did it with angular1 and `promises`, do you see better way to achieve it?

Comment: Do you use `auth$` anywhere else in `authService`? if no then you don't need to subscribe to in `autheService`...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Why would you subscribe to in `sharedService`, when this approach can be used !

```
@Injectable()
export class Auth {
    constructor(public http: Http) {}

    public authentificate(credentials: CredentialsModel) {
        const headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

            return  this.http.post(config.LOGIN_URL, JSON.stringify(credentials), {headers})      //added return
            .map(res => res.json());
            //.subscribe(
            //    data => this._saveJwt(data.id_token),
            //    err => console.log(err)
            //);
    }
}
```

---

```
@Component({
selector: 'my-login',
    template: `<form (submit)="submitForm($event)">
                <input [(ngModel)]="cred.username" type="text" required autofocus>
                <input [(ngModel)]="cred.password" type="password" required>
                <button type="submit">Connexion</button>
            </form>`
})
export class LoginComponent {
    private cred: CredentialsModel = new CredentialsModel();

    constructor(public auth: Auth) {}

    submitForm(e: MouseEvent) {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.auth.authentificate(this.cred).subscribe(
               (data) => {this.auth._saveJwt(data.id_token)},  //changed
               (err)=>console.log(err),
               ()=>console.log("Done")
            );
    }
}
```

---

***Edit*** 
still if you want to subscribe in `sharedService` and `component` you can surely go with this approach. ***But I'd not recommend this*** rather before edited section seems perfect to me.

I can't test it with your code. but look at my [example here(tested)](http://plnkr.co/edit/UMMFk57seNrxqdgyeQIT?p=preview). click on `myFriends tab`,check browser console and UI. browser console shows subscription result of `sharedService` & UI shows subscription result of `component`.

---

```
  @Injectable()
  export class Auth {
    constructor(public http: Http) {}

    public authentificate(credentials: CredentialsModel) {
        const headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

           var sub =  this.http.post(config.LOGIN_URL, JSON.stringify(credentials), {headers})      //added return
            .map(res => res.json());

           sub.subscribe(
                data => this._saveJwt(data.id_token),
                err => console.log(err)
               );

           return sub;
    }
}
```

---

```
export class LoginComponent {
    private cred: CredentialsModel = new CredentialsModel();

    constructor(public auth: Auth) {}

    submitForm(e: MouseEvent) {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.auth.authentificate(this.cred).subscribe(
               (data) => {this.auth._saveJwt(data.id_token)},  //not necessary to call _saveJwt from here now.
               (err)=>console.log(err),
               ()=>console.log("Done")
            );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks I like this way, it solves perfectly my case but it doesn't answer my global problem of the better way to subscribe an observable inside a component and a service.

Comment: Finally found a solution. updating an answer.

Comment: Please keep in mind that i havent tested your code so if you find any difficulty with your code, you can check my tested code and make your code according to it....

Comment: Just tested your plunkr, works good and without using `share` operator.. But I agree with you, I will use your first solution. Thx for your help!

Comment: Now if this is what you wanted, you should accept it as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can only subscribe to event in the service and return the corresponding observable:

```
public authentificate(credentials: CredentialsModel) {
    const headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    var obs = this.http.post(config.LOGIN_URL, JSON.stringify(credentials), {headers})
        .map(res => res.json())
        .subscribe(
            data => this._saveJwt(data.id_token)
        );

    return obs;
}
```

If errors occur, you can catch it using the `catch` operator:

```
submitForm(e: MouseEvent) {
  e.preventDefault();
  this.auth.authentificate(this.cred).catch((err) => {
    console.log('ERROR component', err);
  });
}
```

**Edit**

If you want to subscribe twice to an observable, you need to make it "hot" by calling the `share` method.

You could also leverage the `do` operator and only subscribe in the component:

```
public authentificate(credentials: CredentialsModel) {
    const headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    return this.http.post(config.LOGIN_URL, JSON.stringify(credentials), {headers})
        .map(res => res.json())
        .do(
            data => this._saveJwt(data.id_token)
        );
}
```

Comment: I tried this but `authentificate` is not returning an `observable` anymore but a `Subscriber` so impossible to call `catch` or `subscribe` on it..

Comment: Ok thanks, so I did it correctly. I asked because it seemed not elegant for me but maybe in my case going back with a `promise` with a `then()` inside my service and inside my component is more adapted

Comment: Perhaps it's not necessary to subscribe in the service. I updated my question with another approach based on the `do` operator...

Comment: yes nice solution but I imagine `do` will be called when success and error?